# Insert input into div jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, html, input, append

I need some help.
I have a form with some inputs and he sorted with divs.
I want to insert into the div more inputs so I tried to do something like this-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#more").click(function(){
    $("#div_name").append("<input type=\"text\" name\"test\" value=\"test\" />");
  });
});
```

And the html is

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form_name">
   <input type="text" name="text_input" value="test" />
   <div id="div_name"></div>
   <input type="button" id="more" value="Add more" />
</form>
```

And it's works and add the inputs great, but when I send the form he won't send the input that the jquery added because if I'll do print_r($_POST); he will show me all the posts except those I just added, so the output will be

```
        Array
(
    [text_input] => test
)
```

also when I used the jQuery code above.
But when I'm doing $("form").append(...); , everything is going great but the input isn't in the div.
Thank you. :)

Comment: you should post your html as well

Comment: is the #div_name in the form?

Comment: Can you show what's being rendered after the append?

Comment: @Videron I found your issue in my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all the dynamic inputs you are inserting into the form will all have the same name so that wont work.  You will either have to append a number/String to the end of the name to differentiate each input data.

Here's a fiddle for you to checkout and it shows that the form element does contain the dynamically created input elements. http://jsfiddle.net/umuff/

UPDATE:

Found what you are doing wrong

name\"test\" <=== You forgot the equals sign after name

heres a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/umuff/1/

Answer (score 1):

your div should be inside the form. just move the form's beginning tag to be before the div, and the /form tag after the /div.

if this doesn't work do it the other way around:

```
<div id="...">
   <form>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I did
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form_name">
<div id="div_id"></div>
</form>
And nothing..